# Autocomplete with jQuery UI returns ArgumentNullException

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I am trying to put a simple autocomplete function in my search bar
in an ASP.Net website but every time I type in the field I get a System ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.' for the variable searchString.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
        source: '/Home/Autocomplete/'
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="searchString" autocomplete="off" id="autocomplete" class="ui-autocomplete-input" placeholder="Search..." />
```

Method:

```
 public ActionResult Autocomplete(string searchString)
    {
        var items  = repository.Products.Where(p => p.Name.ToLower().Contains(searchString));


        return Json(items);
    }
```

Appreciate any comments.

Comment: What does the StackTrace of the exception say ? Which line is causing the exception ?

Comment: Does `repository.Products` returns `NULL`?

Comment: It was the searchString that was null because you are supposed to name your variable term in order for jquery to pass it to the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This answer is probably not going to fix your argument null exception, but I see some other issues in your code and want to give you a headsup on that.*

With your current code, the autocomplete method will make a call to your endpoint and pass the value of the input with the querystring `term`

Ex : `/Home/Autocomplete/?term=camera`

So change your action method parameter to `term`. Also, if your `Autocomplete` action method is GET type and you are trying to return JSON from that, you need to use the overload of `Json` method which takes the `JsonRequestBehavior` enum as second parameter. (For .net core version, you do not need to do this)

```
public ActionResult Autocomplete(string term)
{
    var items  = repository.Products
                           .Where(p => p.Name.ToLower().Contains(term));

    return Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Also, If you are using .net core app, you do not need to call `lower` method, instead use the `String.Contains` method overload which takes the `StringComparison` enum as second param.That will work for case insensitive search.

```
public ActionResult Autocomplete(string term)
{
    var items = repository.Products
                          .Where(p => p.Title
                                       .Contains(term,
                                                      StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                                );
    return Json(items);
}
```

Comment: This actually solved my problem I don't get an exception anymore. However instead of showing me the list under the search field I get a message like this at the end of the page "3 results are available, use up and down arrow keys to navigate. " .

Answer (score 0):

Put autocomplete on in the html and use the absolute url “http://domain/path”